# How to check values of OutputField in lightning component on external objects

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, externalobjects

I am trying to check the value based on outputfield, Here everytime it is showing else condition values only. Basically the value might be either 0 or 1. 
Here is my code.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"
            access="global" >
<aura:attribute name = "ContactRecId" type = "String" />
<aura:attribute name="accFields" type="String[]" default="categoryID__c,ExternalId,categoryName__c,DisplayUrl"/>

  <lightning:card footer="external obj info" title="External obj Info Dashboard">
    <aura:set attribute="actions">
        <lightning:button label="New"/>
    </aura:set>
    <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
        Helloo this is about External  record from where it is loaded!!!.  <br />

    </p>
</lightning:card>

 <lightning:card  title="Clinical Impact factors">

       <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
             <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="x000o000000uyQUAAY" density="comfy"  objectApiName="Categorys__x"   class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_edit slds-form-element_readonly slds-form-element_stacked  slds-hint-parent"  > <!--fields="{!v.accFields}"  -->


                 <aura:if isTrue="{! (v.accFields.ExternalId) == '1' }"> 
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="DisplayUrl" />
                     <lightning:outputField fieldName="categoryName__c"/>
                     <aura:set attribute="else">
                          <lightning:outputField fieldName="categoryID__c"/>


                     </aura:set>
                 </aura:if> 

                 </lightning:recordViewForm>
        </div>

</lightning:card>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind you are always ending with else condition is as follows:-

As per your definition of attribute:- `<aura:attribute name="accFields" type="String[]" default="categoryID__c,ExternalId,categoryName__c,DisplayUrl"/>`

**{!v.accFields.ExternalId}** will not hold any value. **ExternalId** is itself a value of the array. Hence it is not equal to 1.
**accFields** is an attribute of type Array of String.

Understand about data types in Aura Component framework here:- [Basic Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_basic.htm)

## A common use of array of a string is:

```
<aura:component controller="namespace.AttributeTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="favoriteColors" type="String[]" default="cyan, yellow, magenta"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.favoriteColors}" var="s">
        {!s}
    </aura:iteration>
    <lightning:button onclick="{!c.getString}" label="Update"/>
</aura:component>
```